# What are the coefficients in the expansion of $(x+y)(x+2y) \cdots (x+ny)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Are the numbers appearing as coefficients in the following sequence of polynomials known? Is there a known recurrence relation to compute them?

\begin{align*}
  (x+y) &= x+y \\
  (x+y)(x+2y) &= x^2+3yx+2y^2 \\
  (x+y)(x+2y)(x+3y) &= x^3+6yx^2+11y^2x+6y^3 \\
  (x+y)(x+2y)(x+3y)(x+4y) &= x^4+10yx^3+35y^2x^2+50y^3x+24y^4 \\
 &\text{etc.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind, see also http://oeis.org/A094638.

Comment: Pro tip: You can search for any sequence of integers in the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) to see if it has a name.

Comment: @Kevin I hadn't realised that OEIS supports [such searches](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C1%2C3%2C2%2C1%2C6%2C11&sort=&language=english&go=Search)! Consider adding your comment as an answer for higher visibility, as it is a good answer to the question in the title.

Comment: Actually that is how I found the answer:)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences®](http://oeis.org) is a
searchable database of many integer sequences, and (as @Kevin also said in a comment) can be a valuable
tool to identify a particular sequence. Searching for
$$
    1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 6, 11, 6, 1, 10, 35, 50, 24
$$
returns as the top result

> [A094638](http://oeis.org/A094638) Triangle read by rows: T(n,k) = |s(n,n+1-k)|, where s(n,k) are the signed Stirling numbers of the first kind (1 <= k <= n; in other words, the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind in reverse order).

So your numbers are [Unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Unsigned_Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) ${ n \brack k }$, which can be defined as the coefficients in the expansion 
$$ \tag{*}
x(x+1)(x+2) \cdots (x+n-1) = \sum_{k=0}^n { n \brack k } x^k
$$

They satisfy various [recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Recurrence_relation), such as
$$
{n+1 \brack k} = n { n \brack k } + { n \brack k-1 }
$$
for $k > 0$, with the initial conditions
$$
 { 0 \brack 0 } = 1 \, , \quad { n \brack 0 } = { 0 \brack n } = 0
$$
for $n > 0$. For more resources about the Stirling numbers and their
relations, see @Michael's comment below.

---

The precise connection with your polynomial expansion is
$$
 (x+y)(x+2y) \cdots (x+ny) = \sum_{k=0}^n { n+1 \brack k+1 } x^k y^{n-k}
$$
This follows from $(*)$ with $n+1$ instead of $n$ and $\frac xy$ instead of $x$.

Comment: “The Art of Computer Programming” (vol. 1) by Knuth is a commonly available ressource with a lot of other relations involving these numbers. The classical “Problems and Theorems in Analysis I” by Polya and Szegö contains much less details about these but also could be consulted.